# php session() doesn't seem to be setting

Tags: php, session, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a page that once logged in will go to a members only page. I had this login working last night, then I changed something and now it appears that the session doesn't stay set. I am losing my mind tonight. Thanks.

**login form**

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 175px">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="submit" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Member Login</button>
</div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Member Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="post" action="" name="login_form">
          <p><input type="email" class="span3" name="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
          <p><input type="password" class="span3" name="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
          <p><button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button></p>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php"); //Establishing connection with our database

$error = ""; //Variable for storing our errors.
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
if(empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
{
$error = "Both fields are required.";
}else
{
// Define $email and $password
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// To protect from MySQL injection
$email = stripslashes($email);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $email);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
$password = sha1($password);

//Check email and password from database
$sql="SELECT id FROM Members WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//If email and password exist in our database then create a session.
//Otherwise echo error.

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
$_SESSION['email'] = $email; // Initializing Session
$error = "Success!";
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
        <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>".$error."</div>";
//header("location: members_only"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}else
{
$error = "Incorrect email or password.";
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
        <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>".$error."</div>";
}

}
}

?>
```

**members only**
this is what I have at the top of my members only page

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
header('Location: index');
}
?>
```

When I complete the login form and submit the correct username and password I am directed to index because my $_SESSION['email'] is not set. If I remove the test it correctly goes to the members only page.

Comment: When troubleshooting, you need to simplify your problem to a minimum and describe clearly what is happening that is not intended or what is not happening which should and I see nothing of that here.

Comment: added a bit more to the description at the bottom as to what I am experiencing. thanks

Comment: Do you mean that when you remove the SQL password check it works?

Comment: If I remove the if (!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
header('Location: index');
} it works, but then if you know the members only page address you don't have to login

Comment: Of course!  That's obviously not what you need to troubleshoot.  You need to troubleshoot as to why it doesn't get set in `login.php`, so probably why the SQL query has a negative result.

Comment: Like I said at first, simplify.  It's also useful to add traces while troubshooting such as `echo`s here and there and possibly a deadly `die()` to avoid the rest from running.

Comment: `// To protect from MySQL injection` Wrong! Use prepared statements.

Comment: I know that the prepared statements are better, but this was just homework. I somehow got it working now, I am not sure what I changed to fix it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. The action in the form had to have the php file called out.